# make a shortcode without editing function.php

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget, shortcode

is it possible to make a shortcode to insert a widget on a page without editing the function.php.

For example: a customer downloads the plugin, entered some data (lika a name or something) and after that all he has to do is to add a short code without editing the function.php.

This is the main widget, more functions are called in there:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    if($instance['layout'] == 1){
        $this->name_content( $instance );
    }

    else{
        $this->name_other_content( $instance );
    }
}

function shortcode_widget() {
 $this->content( $instance );
}
add_shortcode('shortcode_name', 'shortcode_widget');
```

Comment: yes, it's possible. if you need more detailed answer, then you need to provide some  examples of what you did, what want to achieve, what is not working and etc.

Comment: i don't really understand the second paragraph "for example..". but with this plugin you can add php code without editing php-files.